# Multiple Union All in a loop in Laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have Following Table Charge_01, charge_02 upto charge_12.All table have same structure. I am taking two date inputs and calculate the month between those dates. e.g. If user enter **startdate**= 14/01/2018 and **enddate**=14/02/2018. Now i want to get data from both table of month means charge_01 and charge_02. 
This is my code.

```
$i=0;
                  foreach ($month as $dt)// months calculation
                    {
                        if($i==0)
                         $query=DB::table('charge_'.$dt->format("m"))->where('a_party','=',$request->msisdn)->select('charge_'.$dt->format("m").'.*');
                        else
                            $query=$query->unionAll('charge_'.$dt->format("m"))->where('a_party','=',$request->$msisdn)->select('charge_'.$dt->format("m").'.*');
                      $i++;
                    }
                    $charge_data=$query->get();
```

Error is Call to a member function get() on string. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Your where Clause seems to be appended for every Union All which is not possible. Add it at the end

Comment: I want to get result for given query. # of table can be any i want to put UNION All b/w all them. e. g SELECT * FROM charge_01 UNION All SELECT * from charge_02 UNION ALl SELECT * from charge_03